vgcreate: Cannot use /dev/vdb1: device has a signature
When I try to create a new Volume Group with my LVM partition
vgcreate vgdata /dev/vdb1

I've got a message
Cannot use /dev/vdb1: device has a signature

What does it mean?

vgcreate is detecting that /dev/vdb1 either has a LVM PV signature that indicates it already is or has been part of some other Volume Group, or that there is some non-LVM filesystem on it.
A LVM Physical Volume (PV), i.e. a block device that has been initialized to LVM use, can only be part of one Volume Group at a time, but can hold any number of LVM Logical Volumes (LVs).
Using the vgcreate command the way you're trying to do would cause all existing data on /dev/vdb1 to be lost, so the developers found it appropriate to add a safety check to it.
Are you sure you need a new Volume Group? Use pvs to verify the /dev/vdb1 is not already part of a Volume Group you want to keep.
If the filesystem or VG currently on vdb1 is something you are planning to destroy, you can add the --force option to your command, to break the old filesystem/VG (effectively causing loss of its data) and make the partition become a freshly initialized LVM PV for your new vgdata volume group.
But if vdb1 is already part of an active VG, you probably should not destroy it (at least not without properly deactivating it first!). Instead, you might want to just create a new Logical Volume using the existing Volume Group, using the lvcreate command with the existing VG.
